# Creating PySpark UDFs from python method with numpy array input, to calculate and return a single float value

Tags: numpy, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, pyspark

As input I have a csv file with int values in it.

```
spark_df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("../int_values.csv")

df = spark_df.selectExpr("_c0 as something")

_df = df.withColumn("values", df.something.cast(FloatType())).select("values")
```

I also have some python functions designed for numpy array inputs, that I need to apply on the Spark DataFrame.

**The example one:**

```
def calc_sum(float_array):
    return np.sum(float_array)
```

**Real function:**

```
def calc_rms(float_array):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.diff(float_array)**2))
```

*For the 1. example you can use SQL sum like:*

```
_df.groupBy().sum().collect()
```

But, what I need is a standard solution to transform these functions into Spark UDFs

I tried many ways, like:

```
udf_sum = udf(lambda x : calc_sum(x), FloatType())

_df.rdd.flatMap(udf_sum).collect()
```

but it always failed with:

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column:
> Row(values=1114.0) of type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>. For column
> literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

**Is it possible to transform the data in a way that works with these functions?**

**DataFrame sample:**

```
In [6]: spark_df.show()
+----+
| _c0|
+----+
|1114|
|1113|
|1066|
|1119|
|1062|
|1089|
|1093|
| 975|
|1099|
|1062|
|1062|
|1162|
|1057|
|1123|
|1141|
|1089|
|1172|
|1096|
|1164|
|1146|
+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

**Expected output:**

A Float value returned from the UDF.

For the Sum function it should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is groupby and use `collect_list` to get all integer values into an array column then apply your UDF on that column. Also, you need to explicitly return float from `calc_rms`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType


def calc_rms(float_array):
    return float(np.sqrt(np.mean(np.diff(float_array) ** 2)))


calc_rms_udf = F.udf(calc_rms, FloatType())


df.groupby().agg(F.collect_list("_c0").alias("_c0")) \
    .select(calc_rms_udf(F.col("_c0")).alias("rms")) \
    .show()

#+--------+
#|     rms|
#+--------+
#|67.16202|
#+--------+
```